The type 'NSObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0
In my iOS MAUI project, I'm getting an error "The type 'NSObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'" for references that are referring to a Binding Project that has been upgraded to Microsoft.iOS framework.
I can see that the Binding Project is referencing Microsoft.iOS in the decoded DLL but still, the iOS project is throwing the above error for Xamarin.iOS.
I couldn't find much help online and being stuck with this for a long time, any help would be great.

Please add the relevant code where the problem occurred. In addition, in the MAUI project, you can use the NSObject class through using Foundation.

@SeanHe-MSFT  Yes, I know it uses Foundation namespace but IntelliSense doesn't seem to be working on the binding project. Even if it's a new project. But it's referencing Microsoft.iOS on the references. I tried even fixing that IntelliSense issue but it does not seem to be going off. I have uploaded a piece of code from the binding project link. I could not get the sample iOS project (I will keep trying) but we're getting the error in question if we use any type (from the binding project DLL ex: UPCA) in the iOS project

Is the iOS dependencies package used by the MAUI project loaded normally? You can check whether there are warning signs in project -> Dependencies -> net8.0ios

Yes, they're loaded normally and there are no warning signs

What is included in your binding project, it may be that the binding project affected the IntelliSense.
